# How to download website source code (using wget, curl) where you need to accept rules (eg. age, regulations etc.)?

Tags: javascript, curl, command-line, wget, void

On that type of websites you get two buttons EXIT and ENTER.
When you hover on ENTER you get something like :

`javascript:void(0)`

Is there a generic way to pass some argument to the url to be able to download in linux command line ?

I try to pass agrument like TRUE but website is not accepting this.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The answer depends entirely on what the backend of the site is configured to handle. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a generic way to pass some argument to the url to be able to download in linux command line ?

No.

Client-side and server-side code for such things is usually custom (or might be part of a framework, but there are *many* frameworks).